# Guessing Game: computer generated number between 1 and 100 guessed by user

Tags: python, game

The required output is stated just before the `main()` function. Is there a better way to achieve it? I feel like I am repeating code unnecessarily but am unable to find a better way to get the result. Not squeezing the code too much, like one liners, but reasonably using better logic.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

#Time to play a guessing game.

#Enter a number between 1 and 100: 62
#Too high. Try again: 32
#Too low. Try again: 51
#Too low. Try again: 56

#Congratulations! You got it in 4 guesses.

import random

def main():

    return 0

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()

print("Time to play a guessing game.")

val = random.randint(1, 100)
guess = 0
count = 1

guess = input("\n\t\tEnter a number between 1 and 100: ")
guess = int(guess)

print("")
print("randint is", val)
print("")

if (guess == val):
    print("\nCongratulations! You got it in", count, "guesses.")

while(guess != val):

    if guess > val:
        print("Too high. Try again:", guess)
        guess = input("\n\t\tEnter a number between 1 and 100: ")
        guess = int(guess)
        count = count + 1
        if guess == val:
            print("\nCongratulations! You got it in", count, "guesses.")
            break

    elif guess < val:
        print("Too low. Try again:", guess)
        guess = input("\n\t\tEnter a number between 1 and 100: ")
        guess = int(guess)
        count = count + 1
        if guess == val:
            print("\nCongratulations! You got it in", count, "guesses.")
            break
    else:
        pass

print("")
```

Answer (score 10):

1. The pythonic way to do `count = count + 1` is `count += 1`
2. You don't need to repeat the 'guess again' part of the game twice:

   ```
   if guess > val:
       print("Too high. Try again:", guess)  
   elif guess < val:
       print("Too low. Try again:", guess)
   guess = int(input("\n\t\tEnter a number between 1 and 100: "))
   count += 1
   if guess == val:
       print("\nCongratulations! You got it in", count, "guesses.")
       break
   ```
3. You don't need to add the extra `if` statement because if `guess != val`, then the loop with break anyway:

   ```
   while guess != val:
       if guess > val:
           print("Too high. Try again:", guess)  
       elif guess < val:
           print("Too low. Try again:", guess)
       guess = int(input("\n\t\tEnter a number between 1 and 100: "))
       count += 1
   print("Congratulations! You got it in", count, "guesses.")
   ```
4. I think `print("randint is", val)` was probably for testing purposes, but it's still in your code!
5. If you execute your program outside the command module (I'm not quite sure what it's called), the program will close immediately after it's finished; it's always best to give the user the choice of when to quit, so insert this at the end of your code:

   ```
   input("Press enter to quit")
   ```
6. The first section is unneeded:

   ```
   def main():`, `if __name__ == "__main__":
   ```
7. The first `if` statement is also unneeded:

   ```
   if guess == val:
   ```
8. You don't need to define `guess = 0` the first time.

So, all in all, my improvement of your code is:

```
import random
print("Time to play a guessing game.")
val = random.randint(1, 100)
count = 1    
guess = int(input("\n\t\tEnter a number between 1 and 100: "))
while(guess != val):    
    if guess > val:
        print("Too high. Try again:", guess)    
    elif guess < val:
        print("Too low. Try again:", guess)
    guess = int(input("\n\t\tEnter a number between 1 and 100: "))
    count += 1
print("\nCongratulations! You got it in ", count, " guesses.")
input("Press enter to quit.")
```

Comment: I'd use instead of `while guess != val:` is `elif guess == val` then break

Comment: One minor thing: `while(guess != val):` can be changed to `while guess != val:`

Answer (score 3):

How about this:

```
import random

def main():
  print('Time to play a guessing game.')

  val = random.randint(1, 100)
  count = 0

  guess = int(input('\n\tEnter a number between 1 and 100: '))
  while True:
    count += 1
    if guess == val:
      print('\nCongratulations! You got it in ', count, 'guesses.')
      break
    elif guess > val:
      msg = 'Too high.'
    else:
      msg = 'Too low.'
    guess = int(input('{}\tTry again: '.format(msg)))
  return 0

main()
```

Maybe you can draw a flow chart, which can help you get clearer control flow to avoid unnecessary repeating.